# NSIS uninstaller - App Name missing (set dynamically)

Tags: nsis

I created an NSIS installer where the name of the app is taken from an .INI file (it has to be so since it will be used for multiple apps).

```
Name $APP_NAME
....
Function .onInit
    ReadINIStr $R3 ${TECHPUB_INI_FILE} "General" "Installer_name"
    StrCpy $APP_NAME $R3
....
FunctionEnd
....
Section install
....
WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe
....
SectionEnd
```

The app name is correctly shown on the installer and it's the one from the .INI file. When I uninstall the app, the name is missing.

http://i48.tinypic.com/1934w9.png

Everything else works (uninstall removes all it has to remove). Any idea how to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init function of the uninstaller is a separate `un.onInit` function. See [Uninstall Callbacks](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.7.2.2).

Comment: it points to the $EXEDIR: !define TECHPUB_INI_FILE "$EXEDIR\common\Installer.ini" since the .INI file is going to be on the installation medium. No idea how else to point it (nothing else seems to work)

Comment: saved! thank you! added ReadINIStr $R3 "$INSTDIR\common\Installer.ini" "General" "Installer_name"
StrCpy $APP_NAME $R3 to un.onInit and it all works!